# New washing machine seal rubbing, new spider arm?

Tags: washing-machine

I just got a new seal for my washing machine off ebay. After I installed it, it ran a few times successfully, but then started rubbing when it is on the high spin speeds. I am wondering if maybe the spider arm or dampers are gone too? The two springs at the top seem fine.

If I put a little dish soap where the drum was rubbing against the seal it seems to run ok for a while.

The washing machine is an idesit iwme126, the washing machine is intregrated and came with the house so unsure of the history of the machine. The old seal was very mouldy which is why I replaced it. Any other info required let me know. I could attach a video of it running if that would help?

How can I diagnose if the spider arm needs replacing?

Comment: Seals rub to make  seal. Did you check the bearings?

Comment: No not a close inspection, the drum seems to spin ok when I turn it manually apart from rubbing against the seal every couple of turns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the bearing by checking if there was any play between the plastic outer drum and metal inner drum, there was play so the bearings are bad